# Chaining type providers

Tags: f#, type-providers

I am wondering if it is possible to create an XmlProvider from the data provided by an SqlDataProvider.

Naively it would be something like this:

```
type sql = SqlDataProvider<...>

let xml =
    query {
      for item in sql.GetDataContext().Main.Items do
      select item.XmlData
      head
    }

type xmlType = XmlProvider<xml>
```

Of course this fails because xml is not a literal.

I'm curious if this is possible.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is: Yes.

And then the ifs and buts:

Given that the returned xml is structured (as in: about equal each time) then providing an example which is a literal would be ok.

Then the data from the database could be parsed like:

```
let someXmlDataNowType = xmlType.Parse(xml)
```

This is probably not what you want or asked about, but then again the short answer is: No ;-)

If you have a lot of queries with different XML my take would have been to write some code to generate the different XML in some files and even possibly write the f# automagically...

Comment: Both yes and no? Are you an Elf? I could extract a sample of the XML from one of the database entries ahead of time so I can create the XML provider from a file but given that it's in the database anyway I thought there might be away of joining the two together